# can attributes of web components be functions?

Tags: dom, polymer, web-component

One of React's very powerful features is the ability to pass functions as props:

```
<Counter getText={count => `Count: ${count}`} />
```

In `Counter`'s `render` method it can call this function with a `count`:

```
render() {
  const {getText} = this.props
  const {count} = this.state
  return <div className="counter">{getText(count)}</div>
}
```

Of course HTML has a syntax for event handler functions...

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my text color.</p>
```

**but** the arguments the function is called with are hard-coded.  I'm wondering if a web component can be given a function attribute that it can call with any arguments it wants?

Answer (score -1):

yes you can.

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

should be

```
onclick="myFunction.bind(this,arguementsGoHere)"
```

Comment: okay, can you show an example of calling `myFunction` from a web component?

Comment: and by `argumentsGoHere` do you mean the arguments have to be within that string?  Because I was asking if there's a way to pass arguments later instead of writing them in the `onclick` string.

Comment: is this what you are looking for: `<p id="demo" onclick={this.changeColor.bind(this,this.state.color)}>Click me to change my text color.</p>`

Comment: maybe put all your code in context - like one file,  and have your attempted code, so we can see what we need to fix?

Comment: I'm not actually doing any programming, I'm just asking about web components out of curiosity.